# bootstrap-switch LESS client-side usage not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

Has anyone downloaded the bootstrap-switch from http://www.bootstrap-switch.org and modified the index.html to use the src/less/bootstrap3/build.less instead of the css file and add the less compiler from http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage and got it working?

Using Chrome I can see the file are loaded correctly and there are no errors, but the switch isn't rendered properly.

Is it possible that bootstrap-switch doesn't work when compiled client-side?

Comment: Only working on server not in local?

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommend you use http://incident57.com/less/ to compile the less to plain css. It allows you to develop in LESS, but still have the advantage of using plain css. Too many browser related and loading issues with getting LESS to work (for me anyway).